# Eliminate unwanted "hills" in navmesh over a flat floor

Tags: unreal-4, navmesh

So in the image below you can see that my navmesh has these weird hills being formed in it. Any way to remove these? My AI gets stuck on them.

[image: Weird Spike d:]

Comment: Did you turn on show collisions to verify there is nothing actually there?

Comment: Well it is a known problem with UE4 navmesh. You can not eliminate it, you can only adjust a Navmesh generation error. The AI will keep stucking here and there and even on flat surfaces - UE4 AI is really bad, there was a PR half year ago fixing this issue, but I doubt it ever made to the actual engine release